# Model PHP SQL IF Statement Not Working

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am unsur why the below statement is not working basically in a nutshell I am wanting it to run the `$result` statement if only the `$product_id` is not found in the `$images` table.  Is it is found I would like it to then run the `inner` statement.

Both statements do work via phpMyAdmin and the `$result` statement works when just using `$this->db->query`

**Code:**

```
public function product_delete($product_id)
{
    $table = $this->_table_products;
    $images = $this->_table_product_images;

    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT `id` FROM $table WHERE $table.id ='$product_id'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0)
    {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $table.id = '$product_id'");
    }else{
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM $table INNER JOIN $images ON $table.id = $images.product_id WHERE $images.id = $product_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing to if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `{}` around variable name in query. Also use `!=` instead of `!==`

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT `id` FROM {$table} WHERE {$table}.id ='$product_id'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
{
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE {$table}.id = '$product_id'");
}else{
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM {$table} INNER JOIN {$images} ON {$table}.id = {$table}.product_id WHERE {$images}.id = $product_id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `!==` to `!=`

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
{
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $table.id = '$product_id'");
}
else
{
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM $table INNER JOIN $images ON $table.id = $images.product_id WHERE $images.id = $product_id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the images table, you should query the table `${images}`, not `${table}`. Also, if you are only interested in finding out how many matching rows there are, it's best to use the `COUNT()` function in MySQL. That way you always get one row instead of potentially 100,000s. Using the function `mysqli_num_rows()` has the disadvantage that you're loosing the flexibility that the CodeIgniter database class introduces.

So your code should be something like

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) `cnt` FROM ${images} WHERE ${images}.product_id ='$product_id'");

$row = $result->row();

if($row['cnt'] != 0) {
    // found something
```

If the variable name is unclear in a string, you can use brackets to tell PHP what you want. `"${foo}bar"` means that the variable is `$foo` and `bar` is just some string to append to the variable content. It also helps to improve readability. And I changed `!==` to `!=` because I'm not familiar enough with CI and I do not know if the value will be an integer or the string representation of an integer.